# How to create a loop which will check if Jtree contains a value from Set <string> and reselects them automatically after a button press?

Tags: java, loops, button, set, jtree

How to create a loop which will check if the `jtree` contains any elements from the `set <string>` and reselect them automatically after a press of button.

I store my info like this:

```
testNos = (currentTestLabel.getText() + classLabel.getText());

mySet1.add(testNos);
```

I've been struggling with this for days, and I wasn't able to find any info on this or how to achieve that. Any help would be great.

Comment: You should at least give us an example of which control you have, what you store in the jtree and in the set and finally what you wish to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that will return you all the matching nodes. You can do it by iterating over all the nodes in the tree and check if there names matches the one in the set.

```
   public java.util.List<TreePath> find(DefaultMutableTreeNode root, Set<String> s) {
        java.util.List<TreePath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> e = root.depthFirstEnumeration();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = e.nextElement();
            if (s.contains(node.toString())) {
                paths.add(new TreePath(node.getPath()));
            }
        }
        return paths;
    }
```

You can then call this method passing the tree node and Set of strings. Please note that you will need to cast the `root` to `DefaultMutableTreeNode` because `getRoot` returns Object.

```
java.util.List<TreePath> treePaths=   find((DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot(), someSet);
```

Then iterate over treePaths and invoke `removeSelectionPath` to deselect the nodes

```
    for (TreePath treePath : treePaths) {
        tree.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionPath(treePath);
    }
```

Comment: Why is there public in front of it?

Comment: @epouve If You mean in front of `find` method, then it is not necessary you can choose whichever access modifier you want depending on your needs